# Data Table Not Loading in Selenium after clicking on form submit button

Tags: selenium, automation, browser-automation, information-extraction

In this URL : https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/derivatives/equities/historical_fo.htm

I'm trying to get data after giving values in Selenium.

What I'm supposed to get (Manual Output) :
[image: Desired output, as table]

What I actually get  (Via Selenium Automation), a white box with no data:
[image: the table does not load, I'm only getting a white box which pops up when submit is clicked on]

My code :

```
Select instrument = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='instrumentType']")));
        Select symbol = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='symbol']")));
        Select year = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='year']")));
        Select expiryDate = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='expiryDate']")));
        Select optionType = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='optionType']")));
 instrument.selectByVisibleText("Index Options");
        symbol.selectByVisibleText("BANK NIFTY");
        optionType.selectByVisibleText("PE");
        year.selectByVisibleText("2016");
```

In the above lines, I select each dropdown list and set value for the dropdown lists

`Thread.sleep(3000);` // wait for 3000 milliseconds

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='strikePrice']")).sendKeys(""+strikePr);
```

enter strike price in text input

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='rdDateToDate']")).click();
```

//select radio button to select range of dates for table

```
    expiryDate.selectByVisibleText("09-06-2016");
    sleepTime(3000);
    try {

        (By.xpath("//input[@id='fromDate']"))
        .sendKeys(DaysBefore.DaysBeforestring("09-06-2016", 2));} catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        driver.findElement
        (By.xpath("//input[@id='toDate']"))
        .sendKeys(DaysBefore.DaysBeforestring("09-06-2016", 1))
            } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

//function to return previous date as string. here we're taking T-2 as from-date, and T-1 as to-date

```
    sleepTime(3000);

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='getButton']")).click(); } sleepTime(3000);
    }
```

//clicking on the form to submit data. have tried submit() function as well, same result. table isn't coming up when automated

Comment: Are you sure if your site is working as expected ? because even if you manually hit with required data I cant see any table

Comment: if you try with the same data i've shared in my screenshot, it should work. its the national stock exchange website for India. results depend on date and price entered. if you need more input values, do let me know, will share.